# convert number into day oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

is it possible to convert a number into a day of the week ?

i've tried

```
       to_date(1,'DAY')
       to_date('1','DAY')
```

with no luck.

Comment: What input do you want?  What output?

Comment: What would you want this to return?  When `to_char` converts a `date` to a day of the week, that relies on NLS settings since different people start their weeks on different days.  Do you want to use those same NLS settings or do you want a fixed return value?

Comment: Ok, i'll explain my problem further, i have a table_column in witch numbers are stored, specifically numbers from 1 to 7. i want to convert those number in strings like 'MONDAY' in order to use them in the function next_day like this -> next_day(sysdate,'MONDAY') .

Comment: @darkpirate, you can use `NEXT_DAY()` with a number - you don't need the day of week name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following to convert the a number into a day of the week. Keep in mind that the result you get will depend on your NLS settings (for example, your week might start on Sunday or it might start on Monday, etc.):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(sysdate, 1), 'Day') FROM dual;
```

The above will convert the number into a day of the week name (e.g., `Sunday`). If you want a date, simply use:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(sysdate, 1) FROM dual;
```

This will return the next occurrence of that day of the week (on my system, for example, it returns the next Sunday).

Comment: thank you david, i probably overlooked that in the function description! You've been concise and clear. thank you very much

Comment: @darkpirate, actually I think this use of `NEXT_DAY()` is undocumented. But it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, this is one place where the old-fashioned `decode()` is useful:

```
select decode(<your number>, 1, 'Mon', 2, 'Tue', . . . , 7, 'Sun')
```

This is interpreting the question as returning the day of the week for the day number of the week.  Admittedly, the code does suggest that you actually want a date, but that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```
select level as number, 
    to_char(level+trunc(sysdate,'D'),'Day') as day
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

NUMBER DAY                                
--- ------------------------------------
  1 Monday                               
  2 Tuesday                              
  3 Wednesday                            
  4 Thursday                             
  5 Friday                               
  6 Saturday                             
  7 Sunday
```

Comment: The values you show are only the result of the query is executed on the first-day of the week on an NLS-language that has monday as day 1.